# Почему нельзя перехватить out of range исключение?

Tags: c++

```
    try
    {
        std::vector<int>v;
    int t=-1;
    while(std::cin>>t)
    v.push_back(t);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<=v.size();++i)
    std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }


    catch(std::out_of_range)
    {
    //hadlne an exception();

    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Здесь нечего перехватывать. Метод `std::vector<>::operator []` не бросает исключений. Ваш код просто порождает неопределенное поведение при выходе за пределы вектора. Никаких исключений.

Если вы хотите получить исключение `std::out_of_range` - используйте метод `std::vector<>::at` вместо `[]`.